# Conditional subsetting of data frame based on HH:MM:SS formatted column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

So I have a large df with a column called "session" that is in the format 
        HH:MM:SS (e.g. 0:35:24 for 35 mins and 24 secs).

I want to create a subset of the df based on a condition like > 2 mins or < 90 mins from the "sessions" column

I tried to first convert the column format into Date:

```
    df$session <- as.Date(df$session, "%h/%m/%s")
```

I was going to then use the subset() to create my conditional subset but the above code generates a column of NAs.

```
    subset.morethan2min <-subset(df, CONDITION)
```

where CONDITION is df$session >2 mins?

How should I manipulate the "session" column in order to be able to subset on a condition as described?

Sorry very new to R so welcome any suggestions.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I converted the session column to POSIXct then used function minute() from lubridate package to get numerical values for hour and minute components.  Not a near solution but seems to work for my needs right now. Still would welcome a neater solution though.

```
    df$sessionPOSIX <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$session, "%H:%M:%S"))

    df$minute <- minute(df$sessionPOSIX)

    subset.morethan2min <- subset(df, minute > 2)
```

Comment: Is it really a "Date"? It seems like `as.Date` may not be the function you want for this.  See `?DateTimeClasses`, as I am not completely up to speed on dates and times in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date is not the same as a period. The easiest way to handle periods is to use the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)

df$session <- hms(df$session)

df.morethan2min <- subset(df, df$session > period(2, 'minute'))
```

`hms()` converts your duration stamps into period objects, and `period()` creates a period object of the specified length for comparison.

As an aside, there are numerous  other ways to subset data frames, including the `[` operator and functions like `filter()` in the `dplyr` package, but that's beyond what you need for your current purposes.

Comment: This is way easier than what I was trying to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably simpler ways to do this, but here's one solution:

```
set.seed(1234)
tDF <- data.frame(
  Val = rnorm(100),
  Session = paste0(
    sample(0:23,100,replace=TRUE),
    ":",
    sample(0:59,100,replace=TRUE),
    ":",
    sample(0:59,100,replace=TRUE),
    sep="",collapse=NULL),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
##
toSec <- function(hms){
  Long <- as.POSIXct(
    paste0(
      "2013-01-01 ",
      hms),
    format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    tz="America/New_York")
  3600*as.numeric(substr(Long,12,13))+
    60*as.numeric(substr(Long,15,16))+
    as.numeric(substr(Long,18,19))
}
##
tDF <- cbind(
  tDF,
  Seconds = toSec(tDF$Session),
  Minutes = toSec(tDF$Session)/60
)
##
> head(tDF)
         Val  Session Seconds   Minutes
1 -1.2070657 15:21:41   55301  921.6833
2  0.2774292 12:58:24   46704  778.4000
3  1.0844412  7:32:45   27165  452.7500
4 -2.3456977 18:26:46   66406 1106.7667
5  0.4291247 12:56:34   46594  776.5667
6  0.5060559 17:27:11   62831 1047.1833
```

Then you can just subset your data easily by doing `subset(Data, Minutes > some_number)`.